when I open the vscode's terminal than default terminal change to "JavaSE - 21" automatically
No matter how many times I change it to "bash",but it always changes to "JavaSE - 21" EVERYTIME!!!!!
It's not changed until opening internal terminal, but when I open the terminal? then setting.json are change.
I don't know why this happened.
This problem make me crazy!!!!!!
How can I solve it??????

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

code->preferens->settings->find 'terminal' and find this blok:
Terminal › Integrated › Shell Integration: Enabled (Also changed to User)
Determines whether shell integration is automatically enabled to support features like rich command tracing and current working directory detection.
Shell integration works by injecting a startup script into the shell.
The script tells VS Code what is happening in the terminal.
Supported shells:

Linux/macOS: bash, fish, pwsh, zsh
• Windows: pwsh, git bash
This setting only applies when creating terminals, so you will need to restart your terminals for it to take effect.
Note that script injection may not work if you have defined custom arguments in the terminal profile, enabled Editor: Accessibility
Support, are using [complex bash PROMPT_COMMAND ]
(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_complex-bash-) or other unsupported settings. To disable decorations, see Terminal › Integrated › Shell Integrations: Decorations

